# Why Vue's v-if doesnt render block in time?

Tags: vuejs2

The small test components:

```
<template>
  <div 
    id="report-chart"
    v-if="report"
  ></div>
  <div v-else>
    Loading...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ReportChart from '@/components/report-chart'
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        report: null
      }
    },
    watch: {
      report (value) {
        if (value) this.showReport()
      }
    },
    methods = {
      showReport () {
        // I expect the 'report-chart' elem exists but Im wrong.
        console.log(document.getElementById('report-chart')) // -> null
      },
      loadReport () {
        // returns Promise
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.loadReport().then(data => (this.report = data))
    }
  }
</script>
```

When I call console.log() I expect the elem 'report-chart' is rendered but is't wrong. Why? All the needed triggers is on and DIV have to be in document.

Comment: i dont really understand what you want to achive but try created() instead of mounted()

Comment: The goal is to show loading indicator, then (when data loaded) show div[@id='report-chart'] and render custom component ReportChart inside that div.

If I change mounted  to created effect will be the same. I've edited code to find it more understandable )

Comment: I threw together a small demo based off your code and as far as I can see it's all working correctly. https://codesandbox.io/s/ppnv5nk35x.  What is your promise returning?

Comment: Simple promise from firebase: dataRef.where('date', '<=', now).get().then(querySnapshot => { report = querySnapshot })

Your example is not the same coz of you generate data in DATA section of component instead of load them. Thats the diff pal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue need time to render element with `v-if` after condition comes true. So all I need to wait and modify watcher:

```
watch: {
  report (value) {
    if (value) {
      this.$nextTick().then(() => this.showReport())
    }
  }
}
```

Peace!

Answer (score -1):

To make it work, remove the if on the required element.

```
<template>
    <div id="report-chart"></div>
    <div v-if="!report">
        Loading...
    </div>
</template>
```

Remove the watch, and move you render function to mounted method.

```
mounted () {
  this.loadReport().then(data => {this.report = data; this.showReport();})
}
```

Comment: Wrong way. I do not need empty elements in the documents. And I want to understand how it works.

Comment: In my understanding, you want do load a chart in that element, right? I wouldn't call it empty really.

Comment: Right. But primary mission is to understand how it works and what approach is right.